# Dataframe - difference of rows by some style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I want the difference of column 'position' by the column 'Seg' with 'x' adjacent.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
mydict = {'position':['0.0', '0.433', '2.013', '3.593', '5.173', '6.753', '6.9'],'Seg':['x', 'x', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'x']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)
df

   position  Seg
0      0.0    x
1    0.433    x
2    2.013  NaN
3    3.593  NaN
4    5.173  NaN
5    6.753  NaN
6      6.9    x
```

How can I get the difference 'diff' and 'Seg ID'? Note: 'x' can randomly be at any rows and 'Seg ID' changes accordingly.

```
   position  Seg   diff  Seg ID
0      0.0    x     NaN    NaN
1    0.433    x   0.433  Seg 1
2    2.013  NaN    NaN    NaN
3    3.593  NaN    NaN    NaN
4    5.173  NaN    NaN    NaN
5    6.753  NaN    NaN    NaN
6      6.9    x   6.467  Seg 2
```

Comment: What is logic for `Seg ID` ? It is counter for non missing values in `diff` ?

Comment: @ jezrael: For 'Seg ID', it starts from 1 and add 1 for the followed.

Comment: I changed data in my answer, my logic is correct?

Comment: @ jezrael: It is correct. I have upvoted it.

Comment: some problem with my answer?

Comment: @ jezrael: No. The update is too often. I am a little lost which answer I am looking at and "Accept". I have "Accept" your answer, the only "Accept" answer because yours is earlier than @ mozway's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert strings in `position` to float by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) first:

```
df['position'] = df['position'].astype(float)
```

Get differencies by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) by mask - compare by `x`:

```
m = df['Seg'].eq('x')
df.loc[m, 'diff'] = df.loc[m, 'position'].diff()
```

Create counter if difference is not `NaN` by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
m1 = df['diff'].notna()
df.loc[m1, 'Seg ID'] = 'Seg ' + m1[m1].cumsum().astype(str)
print (df)
   position  Seg   diff Seg ID
0     0.000    x    NaN    NaN
1     0.433    x  0.433  Seg 1
2     2.013  NaN    NaN    NaN
3     3.593  NaN    NaN    NaN
4     5.173  NaN    NaN    NaN
5     6.753  NaN    NaN    NaN
6     6.900    x  6.467  Seg 2
```

Different input data:

```
mydict = {'position':['0.0', '0.433', '2.013', '3.593', '5.173', '6.753', '6.9'],
          'Seg':['x', 'x', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'x', 'x']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)
print (df)
  position  Seg
0      0.0    x
1    0.433    x
2    2.013  NaN
3    3.593  NaN
4    5.173  NaN
5    6.753    x
6      6.9    x

df['position'] = df['position'].astype(float)
m = df['Seg'].eq('x')
df.loc[m, 'diff'] = df.loc[m, 'position'].diff()

m1 = df['diff'].notna()
df.loc[m1, 'Seg ID'] = 'Seg ' + m1[m1].cumsum().astype(str)

print (df)
   position  Seg   diff Seg ID
0     0.000    x    NaN    NaN
1     0.433    x  0.433  Seg 1
2     2.013  NaN    NaN    NaN
3     3.593  NaN    NaN    NaN
4     5.173  NaN    NaN    NaN
5     6.753    x  6.320  Seg 2
6     6.900    x  0.147  Seg 3
```

Comment: Thanks for adding another example.

Comment: @warem - ya, only one answer should be accepted, not both.

Comment: @jezrael: I didn't know the rule. Sorry about it.

Comment: @warem Yes, it is up to you, who answer is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Select the rows and [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['position'] = df['position'].astype(float)

df['diff'] = df.loc[df['Seg'].eq('x'), 'position'].diff()
```

If you also want the index:

```
m = df['Seg'].eq('x')
df.loc[m, 'Seg ID'] = 'Seg ' + m[df['diff'].notna()].cumsum().astype(str)
```

Output:

```
   position  Seg   diff Seg ID
0     0.000    x    NaN    NaN
1     0.433    x  0.433  Seg 1
2     2.013  NaN    NaN    NaN
3     3.593  NaN    NaN    NaN
4     5.173  NaN    NaN    NaN
5     6.753  NaN    NaN    NaN
6     6.900    x  6.467  Seg 2
```

Comment: For 'Seg ID', it must start from 1 and it must be `int`. So, it would be 'Seg 1', 'Seg 2' etc or simply 1, 2 etc. Can I get this?

Comment: @warem sure, let me update

Comment: I have to cancel "Accept' your answer because I have accepted jezrael's answer. Sorry about it.